# Laravel Intersection of Model Data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have Article and Tag models with corresponding functions in each files:

Article.php:

```
public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Tag.php:

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
    }
```

On Blade view, I can access articles with a corresponding tag by calling

```
@foreach($tag->articles as $article)
   ...
@endforeach
```

From above, I can access a number of articles for a single tag. How can we filter articles with multiple tags, say only articles which have both `tag1` and `tag2` in a Tag model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [native way](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) of doing what you want:

```
$tags = ['tag1', 'tag2'];
$articles = Article::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tags) {
    $query->whereIn('tag', $tags);
})->get();
```

If you want, you can use dynamic query scopes to make it slightly more readable:

```
// Article.php

public function scopeTagged($query, $tags)
{
    $query->whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tags) {
        $q->whereIn('tag', (array)$tags);
    });
}
```

That way you could do this when querying articles:

```
Article::tagged('tag1')->get();
Article::tagged(['tag1', 'tag2'])->get();
```